# Access to $__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__ info using standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I query info corresponding to `partition_id` and `last_modified_time` from `$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__` pseudo-table using standard SQL?

AKA, how should I translate

```sql
SELECT
    partition_id,
    last_modified_time as last_modified
FROM
    [Mydataset.Table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

to standard SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__` is supported in Legacy SQL only

The best you can do **without cost incurring** is to query by _PARTITIONTIME (this obviously will work for ingestion time partitioned tables only)

```
SELECT 
    _PARTITIONTIME pt,
    COUNT(1) rows_in_partition
FROM `project.dataset.partitioned_table`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Also, you can submit Feature Request [`here`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1100182)

Comment: That is equivalent to `partition_id` right? Is it also possible to query the last-modified time?

Comment: `partition_id`  - yes, it is ! but `last-modified time` is not available per se  as it is not a meta-data table. if you really need it - you will have to actually query the field in that table (assuming you have it) that corresponds to some creation or ingestion or whatever time - but this will incur query cost!!!

Comment: These are not strictly equivalent. If you run a job that outputs an empty partition, it will show up in `__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__`, but not in the standard SQL group by. The group by only gives you non-empty partitions. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148596543

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility in standard SQL would be to retrieve the information contained within the table metadata `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`. Note that in this case the partitions of all tables within the database are pooled together, and therefore it is convenient to select the specific table in the where clause.

```
SELECT table_name, partition_id, last_modified_time, total_rows
FROM `project.database.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE table_name='product'
ORDER BY partition_id DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Open new Big Query UI in your project. below Query Editor, Go to More-> Query Setting-> SQL dialect -> **enable Legacy.**. And Run below SQL.

**It will give you all information about partitions in the table.**

```
SELECT * FROM
   [<dataset>.<table_name>$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__];
```